# Insert all images on page into bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div element where text with img's is displayed, and when user clicks on it modal bootstrap slider appear.
I need somehow to insert all images from the text field into bootstrap slider, looking for a jquery solution, but have no ideas(tried but didn't work out)

Comment: What you want to do is append one element inside the other. Try googling that and I'm sure something will pop up. Otherwise more code is needed to help.

Comment: Tried to use append method, but currently it doesn't work as i want( it works in a particular different way

Comment: @TarvoMäesepp currently working on that $('.slider-inner').html("<div class='item'>"$img"</div>"); i want to insert img inside of the item, but this doesn't work, is there a like soution?

Answer (score 0):

So i found solution
`

```
    //block with images .imgs-block,
  //block where the items should be copied .imgs-block-popup


        var imgsBlock = $('.imgs-block');
        var imgsBlockPopup = $('.imgs-block-popup');

        imgsBlock.find('img').each(function (i, el) {
          var newImg = $(el).clone();
          var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
          item.append(newImg);
          imgsBlockPopup.append(item);
        });
```

`